# RSpec giving an error on every action in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

this is weird, I'm running `bundle exec guard` on my rails application and I'm getting a long list of errors for every single action in one solitary container. And all the errors are exactly teh same and make no sense, this is what I'm getting for all the actions:

```
1) PriceProfilesController GET index assigns all price_profiles as @price_profiles
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./app/controllers/price_profiles_controller.rb:15:in `extend'

  2) PriceProfilesController GET show assigns the requested price_profile as @price_profile
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
     # ./app/controllers/price_profiles_controller.rb:15:in `extend'

... and so forth
```

Any idea whats going on? The PriceProfileContainer is pretty much a standard scaffold. Where should I be looking at here. The spec files are autogenerated by the scaffold.

UPDATE ----

Here is the Extend function in my controller code:

```
# GET /price_profiles/1/extend
  def extend
    @price_profile = PriceProfile.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.all()
    @locations = Location.all()
    @price_profile_date_range = PriceProfileDateRange.new()

    #respond_to do |format|
    #  format.html # extend.html.erb      
    #end
  end
```

Thats pretty much it.

Comment: I think you are going to need to post your controller code. Based on the error, it appears that in your `price_profiles_controller` you are calling the extend method on line 15 and passing it one parameter where it expects none. But would need to see the code to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-extend) is a core ruby method that allows you to add a module's methods to an object (sort of like include)

Something (you can probably tell by looking at the remainder of the backtrace) is trying to call extend on an instance of your controller, expecting core ruby's extend method, which takes 1 argument) but is instead finding your extend method which takes no arguments (and of course does something completely different).

The easiest thing would be to pick a different name for your method

Comment: Ouch - but as an application its running pretty fine on its own in the browser. I'll make the change and check.

Comment: rspec extends your controllers to do some of its testing magic

Comment: Bingo! Exactly what the problem was here, a simple rename and rspecs happy - thanks a lot, I was almost at my wits end here.